# Python count of words by word length

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was given a .txt file with a text. I have already cleaned the text (removed punctuation, uppercase, symbols), and now I have a string with the words.
I am now trying to get the count of characters `len()` of each item on the string. Then make a plot where N of characters is on the X-axis and the Y-axis is the number of words that have such N `len()` of characters

So far I have:

```
text = "sample.txt"

def count_chars(txt):
    result = 0
    for char in txt:
        result += 1     # same as result = result + 1
    return result

print(count_chars(text))
```

So far this is looking for the total `len()` of the text instead of by word.

I would like to get something like the function Counter `Counter()` this returns the word with the count of how many times it repeated throughout the text.

```
from collections import Counter
word_count=Counter(text)
```

I want to get the # of characters per word. Once we have such a count the plotting should be easier.

Thanks and anything helps!

Comment: Could you explain. Do you want the total length of each word of the text?

Comment: Like the sentence apple tree the total should be 9?

Comment: @Zachary imagine the sentence you mentioned is the .txt file.  
I would like to get:  
apple, 5
tree, 4  
Then group the words by the `len()`

Comment: You requested to _"make a plot where N of characters is on the X-axis and the Y-axis is the number of words that have such N len() of characters"_.  I look at the answer that you have accepted and I cannot understand how building a dictionary whose keys are _words_  and whose values are word lengths is of any help in pursuing your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the accepted answer doesn't solve the problem as it was posed by the querent

> Then make a plot where N of characters is on the X-axis and the Y-axis is the number of words that have such N len() of characters

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ch10 = ... the text of "Moby Dick"'s chapter 10, as found
# in https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm

# split chap10 into a list of words,
words = [w for w in ch10.split() if w]
# some words are joined by an em-dash
words = sum((w.split('—') for w in words), [])
# remove suffixes and one prefix
for suffix in (',','.',':',';','!','?','"'):
    words = [w.removesuffix(suffix) for w in words]
words = [w.removeprefix('"') for w in words]

# count the different lenghts using a dict
d = {}
for w in words:
    l = len(w)
    d[l] = d.get(l, 0) + 1

# retrieve the relevant info from the dict 
lenghts, counts = zip(*d.items())

# plot the relevant info
plt.bar(lenghts, counts)
plt.xticks(range(1, max(lenghts)+1))
plt.xlabel('Word lengths')
plt.ylabel('Word counts')
# what is the longest word?
plt.title(' '.join(w for w in words if len(w)==max(lenghts)))

# T H E   E N D

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you are correct! I was asking for a plot.  
The answer above helped me get to the solution myself, but your answer is more complete. If anyone else finds this post, they can see the plotting in your solution; therefore, I think it deserves to be the solution.  
I also tested it, and it is excellent! I like how the title shows the longest word.  
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, first of all you need to open the `sample.txt` file.

```py
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    text = text_file.read()
```

or

```py
text = open('sample.txt', 'r').read()
```

Now we can count the words in the text and put it, for example, in a dict.

```py
counter_dict = {}
for word in text.split(" "):
    counter_dict[word] = len(word)
print(counter_dict)
```

Comment: The OP requests to _"make a plot where N of characters is on the X-axis and the Y-axis is the number of words that have such N `len()` of characters"_.  How comes that a dictionary whose keys are _words_  and whose values are word lengths is of any help in pursuing OP's intent?